# How to return the final values of the Lagrange multipliers and penalty parameter for the Augmented Lagrangian method (LD_AUGLAG) in nlopt for Python?

Tags: python, nlopt

I am looking to use the Augmented Lagrangian method (LD_AUGLAG) in NLOPT in Python to solve a subproblem for another optimisation strategy. However, to do so, I need to know the final values of the Lagrange multipliers and the penalty parameter at termination.

I have looked through the return options available with the Python version of NLOPT, but have been unable to find a return option for these values.

```py
import nlopt
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x, grad):
    d = x.size
    val = 0.0
    for i in range(d):
        val += 0.5 * (x[i]**4 - 16.0*x[i]**2 + 5.0*x[i])
    return val

def mycons(x, grad):
    val = np.dot(x,x) - 30.0
    return val

n = 2
x0 = np.zeros(n)

local_opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt.LN_BOBYQA, n)
local_opt.set_ftol_rel(1e-10)

opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt.LD_AUGLAG, n)
opt.set_local_optimizer(local_opt)
opt.add_inequality_constraint(mycons, 1e-08)
opt.set_min_objective(myfunc)
x1 = opt.optimize(x0)
print(opt.last_optimum_value())
```

I was hoping within the opt object would be an option to return the value of the Lagrange multiplier and the penalty parameter used at termination. However, there does not appear to be such an option within NLOPT.